# How to create a VSTS pull request status from a successful release?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a data warehouse type application so a simple build is not enough to verify a pull request. We have a release pipeline that automatically triggers a release to a smoke environment. If this deployment is successful the pull request can complete.

It seems that the [Pull Request Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) is perfect for this. However I can't figure out how to get hold of the pullRequestId from within the release.

There is a $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId) variable in the build definition but not in the release definition.

I'm currently testing a hacky solution - during the build phase to write a new file to the artefact directory with the $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId) in it. This is then available to the release. Hopefully there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the build is triggered by PR validation, and the release is triggered by the build artifacts. Then you can **get the pull request Id from the pre-defined variable `$(Release.Artifacts.vs2017.SourceBranch)`**.

Since the build is triggered for PR validation, so the source branch format will be:

```
refs/pull/{PullRequestId}/merge
```

During release, you can get the source branch by `$(Release.Artifacts.vs2017.SourceBranch)`. Then split the string by `/` and you will get the pull request id. Below is an example (the variable `$prid` is for the pull request id):

```
$t="$(Release.Artifacts.vs2017.SourceBranch)"
$pr=$t -split '/'
$prid=$pr[2]
echo "the pull request id is $prid"
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the PR iteration id too? I'd like to reset the policy status on each push.

Comment: What do you mean "PR iteration id"? And what's the difference with PR id? And with PR id, it's enough to change the PR status.

Comment: In the branch policy, for code based checks you should select "Reset status whenever there are new changes" but this brings up a warning "The reset status option limits status to iterations. Attempts to post status on the pull request instead of an iteration will fail." the API to call is this one instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20request%20iteration%20statuses?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Can you show related screen shots for the "Reset status whenever there are new changes" option you set and the the warning?

Comment: Have you setup your own pull reuqest status server? Else PR iteration id can not be used?

Comment: No, I can't see anywhere in the docs that it says this is necessary. It looks like as long as you know the iteration ID you can send a status. BTW, I'm marking this as the answer given the question. Will maybe open a new question specifically for the Iteration ID.

Comment: This is the document for creating a pull reuqest status server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/create-pr-status-server?view=vsts. And if you have any problem wiht iteration ID, you can post a new question then :)